# Type annotation for child classes within parent __init__()

Tags: python, annotations, intellisense, type-hinting, python-typing

Is it possible to get "dynamic" type annotations for child classes from methods defined in the parent?

My situation is this:

```py
class Parent():
  def __init__(self, obj):
    self.obj = obj

class ChildA(Parent):
  class Meta:
    model = ModelA

class ChildB(Parent):
  class Meta:
    model = ModelB
```

The two child classes can be initialized with different objects. I'd like them both to inherit the same `__init__()` method, but also to be able to work in them and have `self.obj` provide intellisense and type hints based on their respective (different) models.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's the relationship between `self.obj` and `model`?

Comment: If this were possible, it would probably be done via a `Generic` `Protocol` that specifies the relationship between the types. I'd need to know background though to say for sure.